# If Column A in file 1 equals Column B in file 2, print line

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files, file 1 looks like:

```
rs12126768  T   0.0252778071842686
rs908742    A   -0.0175531592475892
rs3107147   A   0.0253753063312283
rs3128309   A   0.0284902703996274
rs16824948  T   0.0696193418800571
rs2643888   A   0.0452601314048646
rs3795272   T   -0.0244976316004002
rs2840531   T   -0.0438473997802763
rs10910060  A   0.0364283566135514
rs1129332   T   -0.0274739770007551
```

file 2 looks like:

```
1   rs908742    0   2033256
1   rs3795272   0   2284195
1   rs2840531   0   2286408
1   rs1129332   0   2336210
1   rs7512269   0   2418625
1   rs2247308   0   2445406
1   rs1980789   0   2455863
1   rs3122922   0   2456203
1   rs4648453   0   3025712
1   rs6424069   0   3147030
```

If $1 in file 1 occurs in $2 of file 2, I want it to print the line. So desired output would be:

```
rs908742    A   -0.0175531592475892
rs3795272   T   -0.0244976316004002
rs2840531   T   -0.0438473997802763
rs1129332   T   -0.0274739770007551
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$1 in a' file2 file1
```

Comment: Awesome, this did the trick! Got it written in the lab book now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm I'd suggest to do this is simple hashing.  Read through file2, and memorize everything in $2 of file2.  Then, read through file1, and if $1 in file1 is in memory, print the line.

Here's a perl script that does the trick:

```
use strict;
open FILE2, "file2.txt";
my %remember;
while(<FILE2>) {
    chomp $_;
    my @fields = split;
    $remember{$fields[1]} = 1;
}
open FILE1, "file1.txt";
while(<FILE1>) {
    chomp $_;
    my @fields = split;
    if(defined $remember{$fields[0]}) {
            print "$_\n";
    }
}
```